# How to combine array of boolean functions into a single boolean function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have many arrays of functions of variable length in which each function in an array takes a single argument of the same type and returns true or false.

How can I "compose" these functions together into a single function that tests that each and every component function returns true?

```
var less_than = function(y) {
    function(x) {
    return x < y;
  }
}

var greater_than = function(y) {
    function(x) {
    return x > y;
  }
}

var is_even = function(x) {
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

var fns = [less_than(10), greater_than(1), is_even];

var test_function = combine_tests(fns);
test_function(8) // => true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

```
var functions = [f1, f2, f3];
var arg = "foo";
var result = functions.every(function(func){
    return func(arg);
});
```